# x264 & libavcodec

Tags: windows, x264, libavcodec

After some considerable amount of time while trying to build the ffmpeg static library with the x264 encoder on Windows, I have spent some more time for writing some example with it.
Of course, there are tons of "instructions" on how to build, how to use, bla bla... But, non of them works on Windows. I guess the Linux guys are in better position here. Now, the zillion dollars question is "What's the purpose of all that?". Not only that this is useless on Windows, but I could have bought some third party library that actually works.

If somebody is about to say "But, it works!". I must say, give me a working proof. I don't care about 200x100 at 10fps. I don't need H264 for that. Show me how to compress a single second of 1080i footage. It's H264, it's crossplatform (sounds funny if you ask me), Google is using it (it has to be perfect, right?), some more hipe here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly don't try and build on windows - especially if you use VS - get it from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Then the sequence is something like:

```
 // in ctor
 ffmpeg::avcodec_register_all();   
 ffmpeg::avcodec_init();   
 ffmpeg::av_register_all();

bool createFile(const String &fileName,unsigned int width,unsigned int height,unsigned int fps)
{

   close();

   pFormatCtx=ffmpeg::avformat_alloc_context();
   if(!pFormatCtx)
   {
      printf("Error allocating format context\n");
      return false;
   }


    pOutputFormat = ffmpeg::av_guess_format( "mp4", filename,NULL);


   pFormatCtx->oformat = pOutputFormat;
   _snprintf(pFormatCtx->filename, sizeof(pFormatCtx->filename), "%s",filename);

   // Add the video stream
   pVideoStream = av_new_stream(pFormatCtx,0);
   if(!pVideoStream )
   {
      printf("Could not allocate stream\n");
      return false;
   }


   pCodecCtx=pVideoStream->codec;   
   pCodecCtx->codec_id = pOutputFormat->video_codec;
   pCodecCtx->codec_type = ffmpeg::AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;


    pCodecCtx->width = Width = width;
    pCodecCtx->height = Height = height;    
    pCodecCtx->time_base.num = 1;
    pCodecCtx->time_base.den = Fps = fps;   
    pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = ffmpeg::PIX_FMT_YUV420P;


    // needed for x264 to work
     pCodecCtx->me_range = 16;
     pCodecCtx->max_qdiff = 4;
     pCodecCtx->qmin = 10;
     pCodecCtx->qmax = 51;
     pCodecCtx->qcompress = 0.6;
     pCodecCtx->gop_size = 12;




    avcodec_thread_init(pCodecCtx, 10);


   // some formats want stream headers to be separate
   if(pFormatCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
      pCodecCtx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;


   if (av_set_parameters(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)
   {
      printf("Invalid output format parameters\n");
      return false;
   }

   ffmpeg::dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, pFormatCtx->filename, 1);

   // open_video
   // find the video encoder
   pCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
   if (!pCodec)
   {
      printf("codec not found\n");
      return false;
   }
   // open the codec
   if (avcodec_open(pCodecCtx, pCodec) < 0)
   {
      printf("could not open codec\n");
      return false;
   }

   // Allocate memory for output
   if(!initOutputBuf())
   {
      printf("Can't allocate memory for output bitstream\n");
      return false;
   }

   // Allocate the YUV frame
   if(!initFrame())
   {
      printf("Can't init frame\n");
      return false;
   }

   if (url_fopen(&pFormatCtx->pb,pFormatCtx->filename, URL_WRONLY) < 0)
   {
      printf( "Could not open '%s'\n", pFormatCtx->filename);
      return false;
   }


    av_write_header(pFormatCtx);

   return true;
}
```

Then for each frame

```
int encodeImage(const QImage &img)
{

   if (!convertImage_sws(img)) {     // SWS conversion
       return false;
   }


   ppicture->pts=pCodecCtx->frame_number;

   //memset(outbuf,0,outbuf_size);
   int out_size = ffmpeg::avcodec_encode_video(pCodecCtx,outbuf,outbuf_size,ppicture);

   if (out_size > 0)   {
        ffmpeg::AVPacket pkt; 
        av_init_packet(&pkt);


      if (pCodecCtx->coded_frame->pts != (0x8000000000000000LL))
         pkt.pts= av_rescale_q(pCodecCtx->coded_frame->pts, pCodecCtx->time_base, pVideoStream->time_base);

      if(pCodecCtx->coded_frame->key_frame)
         pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;

      pkt.stream_index= pVideoStream->index;
      pkt.data= outbuf;
      pkt.size= out_size;      
      if (av_write_frame(pFormatCtx, &pkt) < 0 ) {        
          return 0;
      }           
   }

   return out_size;
}

void close()
{

   av_write_trailer(pFormatCtx);

   // close_video
   avcodec_close(pVideoStream->codec);
   freeFrame();
   freeOutputBuf();


   /* free the streams */
   for(int i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
   {
      av_freep(&pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec);
      av_freep(&pFormatCtx->streams[i]);
   }

   // Close file
   url_fclose(pFormatCtx->pb);

   // Free the stream
   av_free(pFormatCtx);

}


bool initFrame()
{
   ppicture = ffmpeg::avcodec_alloc_frame();
   if(ppicture==0)
      return false;

   int size = avpicture_get_size(pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);
   picture_buf = new uint8_t[size];
   if(picture_buf==0)
   {
      av_free(ppicture);
      ppicture=0;
      return false;
   }

   // Setup the planes
   avpicture_fill((ffmpeg::AVPicture *)ppicture, picture_buf,pCodecCtx->pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

   ppicture->pts = 0;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I did pretty much the same thing before posting here. However, I'm still missing the interlaced part. How does the x264 know that it's compressing interlaced frames? And, what I get after the avcodec_encode_video() is some warning about time stamp and return value is zero. According to ffmpeg, the function succeeded, but zero bytes means - nothing. Btw, I need to build the static lib on my own, because every once in a while I find a bug. It is always Windows related ONLY... at least that's what I can tell from the source.

Comment: Btw, I've found another bug... I tried to do exactly what you described. Perhaps some of the tiny differencies are important... av_guess_format( "mp4", szFileName, NULL ); will end up in an infinite loop. :-(

Comment: Same infinite loop behaviour happens with the avformat_alloc_output_context2() function. Anyway, I quit... too much bugs.

Comment: do you have any idea why the avcodec_encode_video() returns zero?

Comment: @moose - if you are trying to use h264 and it's not compiled in, or if any of the required options aren't set (see the // x264 comment)

Comment: x264 is compiled in, there is no doubt about that. Also, I have all these options set from the '// x264 comment'. This zero return value is annoying, I would prefer any kind of error value, because it would mean something...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode with libavcodec+libx264 in interlaced mode, use `CODEC_FLAG_INTERLACED_DCT`. If possible you should use libx264 or the CLI program directly though, it's less work.